# use fillna with condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame which i want to apply [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) as follows:

data:

```
print(for_stack.to_dict())
{2.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 1.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0},
 3.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 2.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': nan},
 4.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 3.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0},
 5.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 4.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': nan},
 6.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 5.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0},
 7.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 6.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 2.0},
 8.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 7.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 3.0},
 9.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 8.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': nan},
 10.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': nan, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0}}
```

I would like to apply the `ffill` only when the value is 8 which should yield the desired output (notice that it filled only when the padding value was 8):

```
{2.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 1.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0},
 3.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 2.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': nan},
 4.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 3.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0},
 5.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 4.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': nan},
 6.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 5.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0},
 7.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 6.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 2.0},
 8.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 7.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 3.0},
 9.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 8.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': nan},
 10.0: {'A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se': 8.0, 'A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h': 1.0}}
```

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: Im not sure if the dictionary's you provided are giving the dataframe you expect. Is your index `A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se` & `A_cj8t63fsb04ga5bm4ongrlx6h`. So only two rows with 9 columns? Or do you have 2 columns and 9 rows?

Comment: 2 rows, 9 columns

Comment: `df.loc['A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se'] =  df.loc['A_cj8e134xu02pixvky4r70o0se'].fillna(method='ffill')`?

Comment: @Erfan this would pad all values, I want only padding in cases where the value in the cell is 8, otherwise, leave as NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to fill `nan` with `8` if only previous value is `8`:

```
df[df.shift().eq(8) & df.isnull()] = 8
```

I missed `ffill` part. Try this naive loop:

```
for col in df.columns:
    filters = df[col].eq(8) | df[col].isnull()
    df.loc[filters,col] = df.loc[filters,col].ffill()
```

---

Edit 2: left in a hurry this morning and did not check this out carefully. Here's a fix:

```
for col in df.columns:
    # mark all na blocks with their previous row
    filters = (~df[col].isna()).cumsum()

    # record those nan blocks with starting 8
    eq8 = filters[df[col].eq(8)]

    # filter these block
    filters = filters.isin(eq8)

    # fill these block with 8
    df.loc[filters, col] = 8
```

Comment: thanks, this would pad only once, while I want to fill it up to the next valid value

Comment: @YehoshaphatSchellekens good point. See update for a quick fix.

Comment: Looks like the `or` nabs `NaN` anywhere

Comment: @RichAndrews it does pick nan everywhere but only fill those right after 8 due to `ffill`

Comment: Good techniques, but it seems to also fill after not 8's.  Invoke this a few times and it should be visible.

 ```df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan,1,8], size=(10,2)), columns=['a', 'b'])
df[df.shift().eq(8) & df.isnull()] = 8
for col in df.columns:
    filters = df[col].eq(8) | df[col].isnull()
    df.loc[filters,col] = df.loc[filters,col].ffill()
```

Comment: @RichAndrews thanks for the comments. You are correct, it didn't work. I already updated the code to fix it.

Comment: @QuangHoang it seems like switching df.loc[filters, col] to df.loc[filters, col+1] does the Job

Answer (score 1):

This is far from ideal, and has the interesting problem of why the function `cond_fill` works only on dataframes of one column. Add a second, and it is not applied.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,8], size=(10,1)), columns=['a'])
#df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,8], size=(10,2)), columns=['a', 'b'])

cols = df.columns

def cond_fill(s):
    fill = False
    for i,x in s.iteritems():
        # set a '9' so we can see the change
        if pd.isnull(x) and fill: s.loc[i] = 9
        else: fill = False

        if x == 8: fill = True

    return x

df.apply(cond_fill)

print(df)
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
     a
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  8.0
5  9.0
6  1.0
7  NaN
8  8.0
9  9.0
```

Comment: thanks, ill give it a look! it seems like the previous answer isn't working, not sure why

Comment: This  doesn't solve your problem because it can do only one column.  But why the apply() is failing for  more than one column is a complete mystery to me and any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely different method, works for n columns and is fast.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print(pd.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,np.nan,8], size=(10,2)), columns=['a', 'b'])

print(df)

for col in df.columns:
    new_col_1 = "{}_1".format(col)
    df[new_col_1] = df[col].fillna(8)
    new_col_2 = "{}_2".format(col)
    df[new_col_2] = df[col].ffill()

    df[col] = df[col].ffill()
    df[col][df[new_col_1] != df[new_col_2]] = np.nan
    df.drop([new_col_1, new_col_2], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Will produce results such as:

```
0.24.2
     a    b
0  8.0  1.0
1  1.0  NaN
2  8.0  8.0
3  1.0  NaN
4  NaN  8.0
5  8.0  NaN
6  1.0  8.0
7  NaN  8.0
8  8.0  1.0
9  NaN  8.0
     a    b
0  8.0  1.0
1  1.0  NaN
2  8.0  8.0
3  1.0  8.0
4  NaN  8.0
5  8.0  8.0
6  1.0  8.0
7  NaN  8.0
8  8.0  1.0
9  8.0  8.0
```